# How to improve MYSQL performance on UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I am optimizing a query which involves a `UNION ALL` of two queries.
Both Queries have been more than optimized and run at less than one second separately.
However, when I perform the union of both, it takes around 30 seconds to calculate everything.

I won't bother you with the specific query, since they are optimized as they get, So let's call them `Optimized_Query_1` and  `Optimized_Query_2`

> Number of rows from Optimized_Query_1 is roughly 100K
>
> Number of rows from Optimized_Query_2 is roughly 200K

```
SELECT * FROM (
   Optimized_Query_1
UNION ALL
   Optimized_Query_2
) U 
ORDER BY START_TIME ASC
```

I do require for teh results to be in order, but I find that with or without the ORDER BY at the end the query takes as much time so shouldn't make no difference.

Apparently the UNION ALL creates a temporary table in memory, from where the final results are then given, is there any way to work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't optimize `UNION ALL`. It simply stacks the two results sets on top of each other. Compared to `UNION` where an extra step is required to remove duplicates, `UNION ALL` is a straight stacking of the two result sets. The `ORDER BY` is likely taking additional time.

You can try creating a `VIEW` out of this query.

Comment: If I remove the ORDER BY the total time to calculate the query takes just as much time. How would creating a VIEW help?

Comment: @jonasMcFerreira Take a look at [this discussion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html#c9063)